# Subprocess32 error on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Начала появляться ошибка в саблайме каждый раз, когда пытаюсь писать код HTML или CSS.
Скрин ошибки:

[image: ошибка]

Скрин папки Packages:

[image: плагины]

Текст из консоли:

> LiveReload: added file /livereload.js with content-type: text/javascript
>   INFO:WebSocketClient:Starting server
>   Emmet: No need to update PyV8
>   Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2017-04-20 22:31:38, next run at 2017-04-20 23:31:38 or after
>   + Info: processing `HTML': please wait...
>   WARNING:process:Could not import subprocess32 module, falling back to subprocess module
>   INFO:codeintel.udl:scan_purelang: path: 'C:\All_mess\Programming\HTMLCSS\Course\kinomonster\index.html' lang: HTML
>   error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted

Пытался загуглить, часто говорят, что проблема в SublimeCodeIntel. Удаляю его и ошибка, вроде, не выскакивает. Но что делать если мне нужен этот плагин? Как решить проблему?

Comment: Что-то запускает python2 скрипт, который пытается импортировать subprocess32 пакет (не в стандартной библиотеке), не найдя его, используется subprocess модуль из стандартной библиотеки (subprocess32 это просто subprocess модуль портированный из Питона 3.2 на Питон 2 — меньше багов, новая функциональность могла быть добавлена). Это показано как warning, поэтому не ясно имеет ли это вообще какое-либо отношение к последующей ошибке. subprocess модуль используется в Питоне для запуска внешних команд.

Comment: У меня [**эта же ошибка**](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker/issues/124) была с пакетом Mediawiker, написал разработчику — тот исправил. Но Вам вряд ли исправят. CodeIntel — пакет, имеющий [**307 открытых issue**](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel), разработка прекратилась. я бы искал альтернативы CodeIntel на Вашем месте. Спасибо.